# On the minimal set of generators of monomial ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am trying to do exercise 2.6 of Hassett's "*Introduction to algebraic geometry*":

> i) Give an example of a monomial ideal $I\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with a minimal set of generators consisting of five elements.
>
> ii) Is there any bound on the number of generators of a monomial ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]?$

It is on the chapter of Gröbner Basis, so it must have something to do with it, but I am not able to find an answer.

i) Thanks to Thomas Andrews' comment, I can guess that $J:=\langle x^{4}, x^{3}y, x^{2}y^{2}, xy^{3}, y^{4}\rangle$ is an ideal of the kind we are looking for.
If I am not wrong, $f$ is in the ideal if and only if each monomial of $f$ is divisible by one of those generators of $J$. From here, I do not know how to prove that there is not a set of $4$ elements that generate $J$.

ii) If i) is correct, the answer to ii) is no, because we can consider
$$
\langle x^{n}, x^{n-1}y,\ldots, xy^{n-1}, y^{n}\rangle
$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.

Comment: Any   set of generators of $J$ contains    $x^3y$ . Else you won't obtain that monomial by combining elements of your claimed generators. Same reasoning for any monomial of degree $4$.

Comment: @georges Suppose there exist $f_{1},\ldots,f_{4}\in J$ monomials such that $J=\langle f_{1},\ldots,f_{4}\rangle$. Then, there is at least one of the original generators that is not associated with any of the $f_{i}$. Let's suppose it is $x^{3}y$. Key lemma in Hassett's book says that $x^{3}y\in J$ implies that $f_{i}|x^{3}y$ for some $i$, but this contradicts that they are not asscociated, because the degree of the elemets of $J$ is at least 4. According to this, a monomial basis of $J$   with less than $5$ elements does not exist. Does this imply that $J$ cannot be generated by 4 elements?

Comment: I think user26857 says it best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show $\dim_K(J_n/\mathfrak mJ_n)=n+1$, where $K$ is a field ($K$ replaces $\mathbb C$ which is not necessary in this story), $J_n=\langle x^{n}, x^{n-1}y,\ldots, xy^{n-1}, y^{n}\rangle$ and $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$. In order to do this we show that the residue classes of $x^{n-i}y^i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ are linearly independent over $K$. Suppose that $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}y+\cdots+a_ny^n\in\mathfrak mJ_n$ with $a_i\in K$. By using the homogeneity we conclude that $a_i=0$ for all $i=0,1,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Here's one with minimal set $3$: $\langle x^2,xy,y^2\rangle$.