# Number of generators of an ideal in $k[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $k$ be any field. We consider the ideal $(x^2, xy, y^2)$ in $k[x,y]$. I need to prove that this ideal can not be generated by two elements.

I tried this by considering the contrapositive, but can't see anything useful. I guess some results from dimension theory will be required. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a hands on calculation you can assume $I$ is generated by two elements $f,g$ with degrees $d_1, d_2$. Then by a few arguments you can filter what $d_1, d_2$ can be. Eventually you run out of possibilities. The process is ugly but works.

Comment: I went that way but I cannot prove that $d_1, d_2 \leq 2$.

Comment: Well actually $d_1, d_2$ cannot be less than two since there are no linear polynomials in $I$. Next use the fact that $x^2, xy, y^2$ are linearly independent. Then you have to argue that as a result no two polynomials of degree two or higher can generate $I$ which rules out everything.

Comment: Only two links out of many: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251419/on-the-minimal-set-of-generators-of-monomial-ideals-in-mathbbcx-y?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622081/ideal-of-mathbbcx-y-not-generated-by-two-elements?rq=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $I=(x^2, xy, y^2)$ and $m=(x,y).$
If $I=(f,g)$, then k-vector, $I/mI$, space has dimension at most $2$. But $x^2+mI, xy+mI, y^2+mI$ are linearly independent in $I/mI$; since every element of $mI$ has degree at least $3.$